# Should I build my simple web application before launching it?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, web-applications

I am building a web application on VS2012.

I am using the ExtJS framework and currently there is no communication with a DB Server or a web service for data.

My question is, once I've launched the project with VS2012, do I have to rebuild the project every time I make changes to my project? Won't it work if I simply refresh the browser?

What's the difference or what problems could arise if I skipped the building part? Currently I launch my app using Quick Debug ( Ctrl + F5 ).

Comment: Usually, you rebuild the project when you change something in the _code behind_ (server-side code).

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side code must be compiled every time that you make changes. But, if you only changes client side, refreshing the browser will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

With Adding to `Freerider`'s Answer
if you are doing

`File`->`New`->`Website`

and create project then you there is no need to rebuild project because it will work as a website just collection of web pages.

but if you do

`File`->`New`->`Project`->`Web Application`

then you are creating an application and in this case your whole server side code(code that you type in vb,c# or f#)`s DLL will be created.

when you built and that will not update until you rebuild it.

that is why you have to rebuild your project.